# GitHub Pages doesn't load CSS

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm making my personal website using `Bootstrap`, `Font Awesome Icons` and my own styling.

When I run my website locally, it seems to work properly, but when I push my changes to my repository, the CSS isn't working.

Example code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/amvro_" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter" style="font-size:40px; color:#2AA3EF" target="_blank"></i></a>
```

For example, this makes a simple blue button, using font awesome and some styling.
When I run it, it shows a blue button, and when I the pointer is hovering the button, it's opacity changes to  70% instead of 100%, but when I push it to gh-pages, it shows a white twitter icon, which doesn't do anything.

[Github Repository](http://github.com/tehalex11/tehalex11.github.io/).

Comment: Which HTML page are you loading, and which stylesheet are you trying to load? What URLs are they being served at? Can you edit your post to show the `<link>` tag that loads that stylesheet? Also, try [hard refreshing](https://superuser.com/q/220179/124606) the page to ensure that your old CSS is not being cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at [your repo](https://github.com/TehAlex11/tehalex11.github.io/tree/dbb276721123e6e38b20caec7523b4a11a74ec70), it appears to be a relative file path issue. In [`index.html`](https://github.com/TehAlex11/tehalex11.github.io/blob/dbb276721123e6e38b20caec7523b4a11a74ec70/index.html#L18), try changing your CSS link from `"styles.css"` to `"./styles.css"`.